# problemas com conversão haml para html/erb

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails

Ola. Tenho o seguinte trecho em haml:

```
 %a.btn.btn-small.notes_campaign{:role => "button", :data => {:campaign_group_id => campaign_group.id}}
   %i.icon-tasks
   Notes
```

E gotaria de passa-lo para erb. Meu problema esta nessa passagem do data, utilizado posteriormente em uma requisição ajax. Ja tentei de diversas formas.

Alguém já passou por isso?